# Bluemix Watson NLC failure to train

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, nl-classifier

I have created a new instance of the Natural Language Classifier in Bluemix.  I deployed the NLC Beta Toolkit application which provided a UI for populating my NLC instance.

I created a data file (csv) and loaded that file into my NLC instance.  It loads well and I can see my Classes and Texts (with assigned Classes).  I hit the Train button and it processes for about 10 seconds before stopping with a red error message saying "Training Error Bad Request".

The error message doesn't really help me, does anyone have any advice as to what may have gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try again? the service was down for a 1 hour window yesterday

Comment: Hey Brett -are you able to make your CSV training data available? This would help us verify that it is valid.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys.  I've solved the initial problem by cutting my data in half.  It loads and trains with 750 texts but fails to train with 1000 texts.  I'd be surprised if it was a formatting issue as I have stripped everything but alphanumeric, commas and full stops from the text.  Is there a maximum number of texts?  If not, then there must be a bad record somewhere between 750 and 1000 which I will try and track down now.

Comment: Hi all, I found the problem.  One of my text strings was an empty string ("") which was causing the 'Bad Gateway' error message.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. One of my text strings was an empty string ("") which was causing the 'Bad Gateway' error message.